# Why amount of used GPU memory doesn't increase when increasing batch size in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an image classifier in Keras. I want to achieve the fastest performance possible, but I notice that the amount of used GPU memory is constant no matter how big a batch is.

I set

```
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

to prevent tf allocating the whole memory.

When I load the model

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model(model_h5_path)
```

`nvidia-smi` shows that 1017MiB is used.

Then I do `model.predict(batch)` using different batch sizes and measure the time here are results I got

Batch 1 — 4.5 ms

Batch 10 — 7 ms

Batch 50 — 22ms

Batch 100 — 45 ms

Batch 1000 — 470ms

And each time `nvidia-smi` shows that only 1017MiB is used.

If I don't set `allow_growth = True` I get the same result.

I expect the amount of used GPU to increase when I increase the batch size. 
I have GeForce RTX 2080 Ti with 11016MiB of memory. So it seems that I don't use the video card to the fullest, since I have 10 GB of unused memory.

Please suggest how can I leverage the unused memory. A naive solution would be to create 10 models, since each of them consumes only 1 GB, but maybe there is a more elegant solution. Or maybe it is supposed to be that way, and it is impossible to use more memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation (https://keras.io/models/sequential/), `predict(...)` takes a parameter `batch_size` -- if you don't specify one, it defaults to 32. Hence the behaviour you see.

It does not matter how many images you put into `batch`, you have to explicitly specify the batch size.